# What's the notation for a 2 input 2 output function?

Tags: functions, notation, coordinate-systems

There are a couple of similar questions on this site but I don't think they answer the same issue (or I don't understand the answers enough to know if they do).

I have a function which takes X,Y coordinates and does some operations, let's say it multiplies the X coordinate by 2 and adds 3, multiplies the Y coordinate by 10, then outputs the new X',Y' coordinates. I'm a programmer and I need to translate my function into an equation suitable for publication.

What is the correct notation for this? I could describe f(x) and f(y) separately, but I keep thinking there must be a notation to do both in one line? There are lots of mathematical operations that work on coordinates...

Comment: Sounds like you want $f(x, y) = (2x+3, 10y)$.

Comment: OK, lets say the function takes in (X,Y) coordinates but outputs something like (temperature,altitude), would it start f(x,y) or would it start f(temperature,altitude)?

Comment: I'll let you answer that yourself by providing this: what if $f takes in a distance and returns a temperature? Generalize.

Comment: If you are a programmer, then your function probably has a single output - a struct with two members, or a vector

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, one possible way of writing your function is the following. Let $(x,y)$ denote a point in space. Because temperature and altitude are scalars, we can say that the temperature at $(x,y)$ is $T(x,y)$, and the altitude at $(x,y)$ is $A(x,y)$. Note that both $T$ and $A$ are functions that take two inputs $(x,y)$, and produce one output. Then, you can introduce a new function $F$ that also takes two inputs, but produces two outputs, i.e.,
$$
F(x,y) = \left(T(x,y), A(x,y) \right).
$$
Basically, every time you call $F$ with the inputs $(x,y)$, internally you call $T$ and $A$ with those same inputs and return their corresponding outputs.